# Music streaming from PC with Ubuntu to audio device via Bluetooth

Tags: python, audio-streaming, pybluez

I want to stream music from my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 to audio device (LG CM2760). I wrote short script in Python where I want to connect with my audio device and then play music. I'm not sure but think that connection is established correct because LG shows my laptops' name. Unfortunately, when I start 'streaming' there is nothing but silence. Problem may be with bytes version of song but I've done 2 days research and found nothing which could help me to solve this.

I tried to convert song to other formats.

```
import bluetooth
from time import sleep

uuid_to_find = "110D"
service_matches = bluetooth.find_service(uuid=uuid_to_find)

first_match = service_matches[0]
port = first_match["port"]
host = first_match["host"]

print(port)
print(host)

sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.L2CAP)
sock.connect((host, port))

song = open("/home/adrian_chlebosz/Downloads/song.wav", 'rb')
byte_array_song = bytearray(song.read())
song.close()

max_mtu_song = list()
for i in range(0, 64000):
    max_mtu_song.append(bytes(byte_array_song[(671 * i):(671 * (i +
                                                                1))]))

for i in range(0, len(max_mtu_song)):
    sock.send(max_mtu_song[i])
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Something tells me that the device on the other end wants more than just a stream of bytes that it doesn't know what to do with. I might be wrong, but this feels like throwing colors at a blind person expecting them to understand what you're giving them. And depending on how you're set up the bluez manager in pulseaudio, it might not even work. Judging by how `find_service` is created, it looks like you need the `name="service name on server"` to connect to - which should tell the device what to expect when you send stuff. Again, these are all speculations and I might be miles off :)

Comment: Bluetooth Audio only supports a handful of audio codecs. PCM is not one of them.

Comment: @szatmary, could you tell me more about this? Which one of audio codecs Bluetooth Audio supports and maybe give a tip how to implement it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I can’t write a summary or Bluetooth audio codecs in a stackoverflow comment. But most of that information is available online already.

Comment: I've made an additional research and found that something like SBC audio codec exists. I know how it works now but it's still not clear to me how to use it to send a song via bluetooth. I downloaded sbc encoder too but it requires "Sun/NeXT audio S16_BE format" which is ".au" audio format as Google said, unfortunately when I want to reformat sbc encoder tells me that I have wrong file format.

Comment: You need to use something like A2DP.  Use the underlying system to handle this for you... it's not trivial.

Comment: I tried to use it but again everything went wrong, so I decided to try using D-Bus to connect my app with process which streams music to audio device. Maybe it will be better idea to solve problem.